Apache Kafka Mirror Maker 2 not wanting to work
I have setup a mirror maker 2 instance up in my vmware but when I go to run the program it does not seem to do anything. I followed the guidance from the Readme and KIP-382 to get this setup. My environment consists of a cluster 5 vms running at the work location (running in vmware) and then a cluster of 5 vms running at the Colo location along with a standalone MM2 VM running at the colo location.
I am setting up a Mirror maker replication for disaster recovery from my works office to our colo in another city. I have gone through the steps of creating another cluster in the Colo to receive the data. I have also setup a stand alone mirror maker cluster of just one node to handle the replication.
Here is my config file I changed the names of the bootstrap servers to protect my work:
# Run with /bin/connect-mirror-maker mm2.properties

# specify any number of cluster aliases
clusters = Work, Colo

# connection information for each cluster
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs for each cluster
# for e.g. "A_host1:9092, A_host2:9092, A_host3:9092"
Work.bootstrap.servers = "A_host1:9092,A_host2:9092,A_host3:9092"
Colo.bootstrap.servers = "B_host1:9092,B_host2:9092,B_host3:9092"

# regex which defines which topics gets replicated. For eg "foo-.*"
topics = .*

# enable and configure individual replication flows
Work->Colo.enabled = true



# Setting replication factor of newly created remote topics
replication.factor=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for mm2 internal topics "heartbeats", "B.checkpoints.internal" and
# "mm2-offset-syncs.B.internal"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=3
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=3
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=3

# The replication factor for connect internal topics "mm2-configs.B.internal", "mm2-offsets.B.internal" and
# "mm2-status.B.internal"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.replication.factor=3

#Whether to periodically check for new topics and partitions

refresh.topics.enabled=true

#Frequency of topic refresh

refresh.topics.interval.seconds=10
# customize as needed
# replication.policy.separator = _
# sync.topic.acls.enabled = false
# emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds = 5

